# Shiro Guice PermissionsResolver

Tags: java, guice, shiro

In the Shiro docs, they configure the global PermissionsResolver in the shiro.ini (see [permissionResolver](http://shiro.apache.org/authorization.html#Authorization-Configuringaglobal%7B%7BPermissionResolver%7D%7D) ).

```
globalPermissionResolver = com.foo.bar.authz.MyPermissionResolver
...
securityManager.authorizer.permissionResolver = $globalPermissionResolver
```

However, I am using Guice, so I don't want to rely on the shiro.ini. I know that I can call 
`setPermissionResolver()` in my `Realm`   but I would rather not since I have multiple `Realm`s.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with calling the setter on all your realms? Its either that, or using shiro.ini.

Comment: I guess. its just that there is a globalPermissionResolver if you attach it to the security manager so i figured there was a way to change it (without the shiro ini) rather than calling that setter everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that by reading the docs mentioned above more carefully, it says that:

`If you want to configure a global PermissionResolver, each Realm that is to receive the configured PermissionResolver must implement the PermisionResolverAware interface. This guarantees that the configured instance can be relayed to each Realm that supports such configuration.`

It also happens that `AuthorizingRealm` already implements this interface so all of the authorizing realms should be able to pick up a `PermissionsResolver`.

In order to bind it with Guice, I added this to my `ShiroWebModule`:

```
    bind(PermissionResolver.class).to(MyPermissionResolver.class).in(Singleton.class);
```